# Failed back up restore from Deja-dup backup

Tags: deja-dup

My Ubuntu crashed and I had to do a complete reinstall.

I have made a full back onto an external hard drive of everything. Deja-dup always verified the backups and I never tested restoring as I trusted that it would work, I trusted the software.

When I run the restore I get an error message which reads;

```
 "Command line error: One of the arguments must be an URL. Examples of URL strings are "scp://user@host.net:1234/path" and "file:///user/local". See the man page for more information. Enter 'duplicity --help' for help screen."
```

I ran the suggested command but don't understand it. Also I've copied the files to my desktop and tried to extract but I get an error that the file type 'difftar' is not supported.

Any advice on how to successfully restore my files?

Answer (score 0):

1. If Deja Dup gives errors, open Terminal and try

   ```
   duplicity --gio file:///media/backup /tmp/restore
   ```
2. Be sure to use `file:///` when on local media because Duplicity expects a URL.