# Deja-dup failing to restore

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I'm using 13.04 and made a full back up using Deja-dup onto and external hard drive.

Deja-dup always verified the back-ups.

When I try to restore through Deja-dup I get a message which I have posted about already ([Failed back up restore from Deja-dup backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343642/failed-back-up-restore-from-deja-dup-backup)) but I am also getting this message the other 50% of the time. "Traceback (most recent call last):File"/usr/bin/duplicity",line 1411,in  with_tempdir(main) and on it goes for about a page.

What am I supposed to do with this information and most importantly how can I successfully restore my backup?

Comment: You'll need to give the whole error message, but try clearing the cache: `rm -r ~/.cache/duplicity`